# Download from AWS S3 bucket using boto3 - incorrect timestamp format

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-s3, boto3

I'm using the boto3 library to retrieve a couple of csvs from an S3 bucket:

```
# Scan s3 verified folder for files
    s3 = boto3.client('s3', aws_access_key_id=aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key=aws_secret_access_key)

    response = s3.list_objects(Bucket=self.bucket, Prefix='UK_entities/Verified_Matches/')

    # Ignore first file entry in dict as is just the folder name. Returns a list of files
    files = response['Contents'][1:]

    # For any files in /s3/verified/ - download them to local /verified_matches/
    for i in range(len(files)):
        s3.download_file(self.bucket, files[i]['Key'], filepath , os.path.basename(files[i]['Key'])))
```

The file that gets downloaded has a column `match_date` which is just a timestamp, and has a value for example 
`03:44.7` 
which isn't correct. When I manually download the csv from the bucket, the same value is shown correctly as 
`2019-08-24 01:03:44.732999`

Can anyone highlight what is happening here and point me in the direction of how I might specify how to handle the retrieval of timestamps?

Comment: How are you examining the .csv file? In a text editor, Excel, Python Pandas, etc. S3 doesn't interpret/parse/alter uploaded data in any way, so the mismatch must be happening either in reading, or in how the file gets generated before it sent to S3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by specifying the exact format I required prior to uploading to the S3 bucket. Despite being able to download the file from S3 manually with the format being correct, the boto3 library somewhere along the way determines the format itself.

```
from dateutil.tz import gettz
import datetime as dt

# clust_df['match_date'] = pd.to_datetime('today') --> old version
df['match_date'] = dt.datetime.now(gettz()).isoformat()
```